# User Meta - Additional Profile Fields - Not showing on Add New User - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding a couple of additional User Profile fields in Wordpress user profiles. Everything seems to be working pretty well for view, edit and update, except the fields are not showing up on 'Add New' user profile creation.

I've got the user_register action there `add_action('user_register', 'tbc_save_extra_profile_fields', 10, 1);`

Also tried with `add_action('user_register', 'tbc_show_extra_profile_fields', 10, 1);`

But the fields are still not coming up for New accounts.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my complete code:

```
function tbc_custom_define() {
  $custom_meta_fields = array();
  $custom_meta_fields['tbc_company_name'] = 'Company name';
  $custom_meta_fields['tbc_company_website'] = 'Company website';
  return $custom_meta_fields;
}

function tbc_show_extra_profile_fields($user) {
  print('<h3>Business information</h3>');

  print('<table class="form-table">');

  $meta_number = 0;
  $custom_meta_fields = tbc_custom_define();
  foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
    $meta_number++;
    print('<tr>');
    print('<th><label for="' . $meta_field_name . '">' . $meta_disp_name . '</label></th>');
    print('<td>');
    print('<input type="text" name="' . $meta_field_name . '" id="' . $meta_field_name . '" value="' . esc_attr( get_the_author_meta($meta_field_name, $user->ID ) ) . '" class="regular-text" /><br />');
    print('<span class="description"></span>');
    print('</td>');
    print('</tr>');
  }
  print('</table>');
}

function tbc_save_extra_profile_fields($user_id) {

  if (!current_user_can('edit_user', $user_id))
    return false;

  $meta_number = 0;
  $custom_meta_fields = cdl_custom_define();
  foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $meta_field_name => $meta_disp_name) {
    $meta_number++;
    update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_field_name, $_POST[$meta_field_name] );
  }
}
add_action('show_user_profile', 'tbc_show_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'tbc_show_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('personal_options_update', 'tbc_save_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('edit_user_profile_update', 'tbc_save_extra_profile_fields');
add_action('user_register', 'tbc_save_extra_profile_fields', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook to new user form is [user_new_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_new_form/):

```php
add_action('user_new_form', 'tbc_show_extra_profile_fields', 99, 1);
add_action('show_user_profile', 'tbc_show_extra_profile_fields', 99, 1);
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'tbc_show_extra_profile_fields', 99, 1);
```

**NOTE:**

When [user_new_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_new_form/) is called, the first parameter will be:

> (string) A contextual string specifying which type of new user form
> the hook follows.

So, if you are going to use the same `tbc_show_extra_profile_fields()` to all hooks, remember to handle the `$user_id` variable properly.

Comment: Legend! Thanks so much Lucius, that works!

Comment: Quick question, what does the `user_register` hook do then?

Comment: It's called after a user is registered with the ID, take a look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/